# Bootstrap Reduce Gaps Between Columns

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 6 columns without problem inside of div but i want to add more columns. I can't add more columns properly because of gaps between columns.I read something about margins but i couldn't do it. So how can i reduce spaces between columns? And is there anyway to resize width of columns according to number of columns? Here is my HTML code(sample for 2 columns) :`

```
<div class="row-fluid hideInIE8 circleStats">

         <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2"> 
            <div ID="ID1" class="circleStatsItemBox red"> 
                <div ID="Mach_Name_1" class="header">1</div> 
                <span class="percent"></span> 
                <div class="circleStat">    
                   <div id="g1"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="f1" class="footer">
                    <span class="number">hours</span>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2"> 
            <div ID="ID1" class="circleStatsItemBox red"> 
                <div ID="Mach_Name_2" class="header">2</div> 
                <span class="percent"></span> 
                <div class="circleStat">    
                   <div id="g1"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="f1" class="footer">
                    <span class="number">hours</span>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where are your columns on your code? I don't see any `col-*` class on your code. In Bootstrap there is a space between cols because they use padding and negative margin to add the responsive functionality. If your question is how to edit the spaces be more clear.  BTW, check: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: @Sharmila `row-fluid` is a Bootstrap 2.3.2 class :p

Comment: @Troyer, this code works at my system without any problem. I think i should change margin of span2 class or may be margin of circleStatsItemBox . But i couldn't be succesfull althought i tried to change these values.